# How to convert a multi-dimensional array to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have a n-by-3 array I wish to convert to a `Dictionary<string,string[]>` where the first column is the key and the rest of the column as an array for the value.

For example:

```
Key = arr[0,0], Value = new string[2] {arr[0,1], arr[0,2]}.
```

I'm aware of `ToDictionary` but I don't know how to set the value part.

```
arr.ToDictionary(x=>arr[x,0],x=>new string[2]{arr[x,1],arr[x,2]});
//This doesn't work!!!
```

How can I set it up correctly?

Comment: Is it a multi-dimensional array or a jagged array? Your example implies jagged.

Comment: It's multi-dimensional.

Comment: @Pikachu620 - If it is multidimensional then the key cannot be `arr[0][0]` - it must be `arr[0, 0]`. Which is it?

Comment: My bad! I'll go edit it!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes not using linq is easier to read and faster:

```
 var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
      dict[arr[i, 0]] = new string[] { arr[i, 1], arr[i, 2] };
```

But when you feel like you REALLY need to use linq:

```
 Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(0))
     .ToDictionary(i => arr[i, 0], i => new string[] {arr[i, 1], arr[i, 2]});
```

Comment: The Linq part is like mine and it doesn't work! Sorry!

Comment: @Pikachu620 No, it uses an Enumerable.Range, which is all you were missing from your original attempt, and then it does work. See a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hig7rW

Comment: It did work! Thanks! I had change the accepted answer to yours!

Answer (score 7):

Multidimensional arrays are a continuous block of memory, so you kind of have to treat them like a single array. Try this:

```
var dict = arr.Cast<string>() 
  .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
  .GroupBy(s => s.i / arr.GetLength(1))
  .ToDictionary(
    g => g.First().s,
    g => g.Skip(1).Select(i => i.s).ToArray()
  );
```

With explanations:

```
// First, cast it to an IEnumerable<string>
var dict = arr.Cast<string>() 

  // Use the Select overload that lets us get the index of the element,
  // And we capture the element's index (i), along with the element itself (s)
  // and put them together into an anonymous type [1]
  .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })

  // .GetLength(dimension) is a method on multidimensional arrays to 
  // get the length of a given dimension (pretty self-explanatory)
  // In this case, we want the second dimension, or how wide each 
  // row is: [x,y] <- we want y
  // Divide the element index (s.i) by that length to get the row index 
  // for that element
  .GroupBy(s => s.i / arr.GetLength(1))

  // Now we have an Grouping<int, IEnumerable<anonymous{string,int}>>
  .ToDictionary(

    // We don't care about the key, since it's the row index, what we want
    // is the string value (the `s` property) from first element in the row
    g => g.First().s,

    // For the value, we want to skip the first element, and extract
    // the string values (the `s` property), and then convert to an array
    g => g.Skip(1).Select(i => i.s).ToArray()
  );
```

[1]: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) for documentation on anonymous types.

Comment: Can you tell me what's **m** please!?

Comment: It was a typo. It's supposed to be `arr`. I've updated the answer and included explanations.

Comment: Can you be so kind and teach me what's **s.i** and **i.s** does please!? Thanks!

Comment: Added a bit more explanation, hopefully it makes things clearer.

Comment: Ehhh readability can be subjective, but I agree 100% on the performance part. LINQ can generally be pretty terrible when it comes to allocations and perf.

Comment: Your answer was great! But it's too complicated! I choose the simplest answer over yours, hope you could understand!

Comment: Sure! The important thing is that you found an answer that works for you and helps you get your work done :)

Comment: @Pikachu620 - Which part do you find complicated?

Comment: **`var dict = arr.Cast<string>() .Select((s, i) => new { s, i }).GroupBy(s => s.i / arr.GetLength(1)).ToDictionary(g => g.First().s,g => g.Skip(1).Select(i => i.s).ToArray());`** compared to **`Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(0)).ToDictionary(i => arr[i, 0], i => new string[] {arr[i, 1], arr[i, 2]});`**   Because I could never remember the first one, and the second one I could!

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest approach I can come up with:

```
var arr = new int[4, 3]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 3, 5, 7 },
    { 5, 8, 11 },
    { 7, 11, 15 },
};

var dict = arr.Cast<int>().Buffer(3).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

That gives me:

[image: dict]

You just need to NuGet "System.Interactive" to get the `Buffer` operator.

Or use this implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Buffer<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    =>
        source
            .Select((t, i) => new { t, i })
            .GroupBy(x => x.i / count)
            .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.t).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your approach was right ,my only doubt is that your array is static or not?

```
arr.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }) .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => new string[2]{x.value[x.index][1],x.value[x.index][2]}));
```

Note: I couldn't execute and check the code ! Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

I had done using Integer. Please Change for your requirements.

```
public static void Main()
{ 
    int row=0 , col=0;
    int[,] array = new int[,]
    {
     { 1, 2, 3 },
     { 4, 5, 6 }, 
     { 7, 8, 9 },
     { 10, 11, 12 } 
    };

    int flag=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Rank; i++)
    {
                if(flag==0)
                {
        row= array.GetLength(i);
                    flag=1;
                }
                else
                {

         col= array.GetLength(i);       
                }

        }

    Dictionary<int,int[,]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int[,]>();

    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {

        dictionary.Add(array[i,0],new int[, ]{{array[i,1]},{array[i,2]}});

    }

    Console.WriteLine(dictionary[4].GetValue(0,0));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I preferred Linq approach!